# Вернуть ссылку на ненайденный объект. Нуль ссылку, спец. ноль-объект или указатель?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, ссылки

Суть функции `inZone()` как можно понять из кода ниже, вернуть объект(ссылку или указатель) из списка, который соответствует некоторому условию. А если ни один не соответствует значит надо сказать нема.
Как бы так вернуть ссылку на объект, но если объект не найден вернуть что-то типа `нуля` или `false`.

```
/** Найти 1ую зону в которую входит значение */
Zone& inZone( float value )
{
    for( int i=0; i < zones.size(); ++i ){
        if( zones[i].inBounds(value) ){
            return zones[i];
        }
    }
    return false; // Не прокатит. Тут разве что вернуть псевдо-ноль объект
    return Zone::NULL_ZONE;  // объявлено в классе как public static const Zone NULL_ZONE; Ест память и выглядит безтолково, как по мне.
    return *(Zone*)NULL;  // это null-reference. DEPRECATED!!! так не делать.
}
```

**Вариант с указателем** не очень нравится. Но думаю что это *простейший и лучший* вариант в данном случае.

```
Zone* inZone( float value )
{
    for( int i=0; i < zones.size(); ++i ){
        if( zones[i].inBounds(value) ){
            return &zones[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int zone_finder(){
    Zone *pzone = inZone(22);  // временный указатель
    if( !pzone )
        /*not found*/;
    Zone &zone = *pzone;
    // далее можно работать с ссылкой, а можно с указателем.
}
```

**Вариант с исключением**

```
Zone& inZone( float value )
{
    for( int i=0; i < zones.size(); ++i ){
        if( zones[i].inBounds(value) ){
            return zones[i];
        }
    }
    throw;
}

int zone_finder(){
    try{
        Zone& zo = inZone(22);
    } catch int(e) {

    }
}
```

мог бы быть хорош для сложных классов, например, потоков ввода/вывода. Однако для этой микрофункции это громоздко.

Критику в студию, пожалуйста. И ваши советы.

Comment: Как объявлена zones? Это глобальная переменная?

Comment: И второй вопрос: доступен ли объект zones в вызывающем коде zone_finder?

Comment: Я возвращаю, обычно, указатель.

Кстати, почему не нравится?

Comment: @sitev_ru, из-за ->, *, &. Ссылка **лаконичнее** и позволяет избежать всех этих часто лишних символов. Кроме того работь  с переопределёнными операторами [],+=,++ и т.д. удобнее.

Comment: > Как объявлена zones? Это глобальная переменная?
*нет. член, класса который тут не прописан.*  

> доступен ли объект zones в вызывающем коде zone_finder?
*да они оба - члены класса.*

*Я не думаю что это имеет принципиальное значение в данном вопросе.*

Comment: В таких случаях используются исключения. Но измените имя — «inZone» подразумевает ответ «да/нет», а никак не возвращение ссылки. «findZone» и исключение будет как раз в тему, ведь не найденная зона для «find» является исключительной ситуацией.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для кода внутри класса я бы не заморачивался, и писал без всякой функции

```
auto findIter = std::find_if(zones.begin(), zones.end(),
                             [value] (auto& z) { return z.inBounds(value); });
if (findIter != zones.end()) ...
```

Это, по идее, устоявшийся паттерн.

Если вам нужно это как публичная функция, я бы вернул наружу `shared_ptr<Zone>`, чтобы не возникало вопросов с тем, кто владелец возвращённого объекта.

---

По поводу остальных вариантов:

- Код `return false;` ужасен и (слава Страуструпу) работает только в PHP. С++ — строго типизированный язык
- Указатель — неплохой вариант, но возникает естественный вопрос о времени жизин объекта и ответственности. Если этот вопрос имеет естественное решение, то почему бы и нет.
- Вариант с исключением зависит от того, *исключительной* ли является ситуация, когда объект не будет найден. Насколько я понимаю, поиск всегда предполагает возможность ничего не найти, поэтому исключение в данном случае — архитектурная ошибка. Хотя технически может быть и допустимо.
- Вариант с Null-объектом мне не нравится вместе со всем паттерном «нулевого» объекта. Он позволяет некоторое время не проверять успешность операции, и писать код как будто ничего не случилось. Тем не менее, на практике во многих случаях это ведёт к тому, что детектирование ошибочной ситуации просто подавляется, и правильная обработка для данного случая не происходит.
- Ну и разыменование нулевого указателя (`*(Zone*)NULL`) — это не deprecated, это undefined behaviour (и я не помню, чтобы это было когда-то разрешено). Просто никогда так не делайте, и больно бейте по пальцам всех, кто делает.

Comment: Это может быть лучшее решение для C++11 и для хорошего STL.

Comment: Однако этот кусок нужен мне для компилятора MDK-ARM с не очень хорошей поддержкой C++11 и довольно паршивой STL. Кроме того embed не любит лишние `маллоки`. Поэтому и список у меня - массиво-подобный. И я остановился на на *ptr. Ставлю галочку ответ, полагаю все варианты рассмотрены. Я же искал решение попроще(посырее).

Comment: @kyb: Для слабо оптимизирующего компилятора лучше быть «ближе к C» — то есть, указатель выглядит наилучшим вариантом.

Answer (score 1):

Для подобных целей в С++ функцию пишут так:

```
bool пример(ваш_класс & параметр){ // работаем с объектом через параметр функции
    параметр.пример = 0; // что нибудь делаем с объектом переданным в параметре через ссылку

    if (все хорошо)
        return false; // ошибок не было
    else
        return true; // была ошибка

}
```

Comment: Полагаю, вы не проникли в суть вопроса. Функция не принимает, а возвращает объект из списка *неизменным*. 
Думаю ваш вариант можно бы слегка перефразировать на `bool пример(класс && куда_положить_ссыль)`. Когда проверю отпишусь.

Comment: @kyb: В C++ `&&` означает вовсе не то, что вы предполагаете.

Comment: мда. && совсем не похоже на  * *  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549151/c-double-address-operator